# Custom order for categorical columns

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to sort by two categorical columns that have specific order:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "nums": [ 1,   2,   3,   4 ],
    "col1": ["A", "B", "B", "A"],
    "col2": ["c", "h", "c", "c"],
})

with pl.StringCache():
    pl.Series([*["B", "A"], *["h", "c"]]).cast(pl.Categorical)
    
    df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col(pl.Utf8).cast(pl.Categorical)
    ).sort(
        # ["col1", "col2"]                      # WRONG!
        pl.col(["col1", "col2"]).to_physical()  # OK
        # "col2"                                # OK
    )
    
    print(df)
```

Correct output:

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ nums ┆ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ cat  ┆ cat  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 2    ┆ B    ┆ h    │
│ 3    ┆ B    ┆ c    │
│ 1    ┆ A    ┆ c    │
│ 4    ┆ A    ┆ c    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I get this output by direct converting categories to integers (i.e. to the serial number) `.sort(pl.col(["col1", "col2"]).to_physical())`, but this code `.sort(["col1", "col2"])` seems should work as well, but output is:

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ nums ┆ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ cat  ┆ cat  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 3    ┆ B    ┆ c    │
│ 2    ┆ B    ┆ h    │ --- should be up
│ 1    ┆ A    ┆ c    │
│ 4    ┆ A    ┆ c    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

*Is it a bug or I mixed up something?*

Comment: Is https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7343 the same issue?

Comment: Yes, it seems they are related. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like it has now been fixed: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7417